# unable to open particular folder inside gallery

Tags: android

how i can open a specific folder in gallery.
ex :name of folder is my folder.
when user click Button it directly open my folder inside default gallery.
how can i do this?

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/video"));
intent.setType("video/mp4");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(openGallary, "Select Video"), 0);
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749351/how-to-open-one-particular-folder-from-gallery-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given twice already. Please use Google first next time. The link that abbas.aniefa gave was my second hit on Google when searching "ACTION_VIEW specific gallery".
The answer is also given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074270/built-in-gallery-in-specific-folder/8255674#8255674).