# Android custom gallery or something simmilar

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gallery, android-scrollview

I have a small and simple question. I need to have a widget in my app that is similar to listview, or image gallery I don't know. So this is my question how can I do something like this in my app?

Here is the widget I am talking about. It has a imageview, and two textviews, and this widget should be able to scroll left or right.
[image]

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390402/how-can-i-display-a-specific-folder-in-android-gallery3d-cooliris/15597083#15597083. Are you looking for something similar?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the view shown above is one item and there would be multiple views like this (e.g. something similar to the list)

Comment: @GauravArora yes, you got me right

Answer (score 0):

I used [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) and custom adapter.

Looks like this:

[image: gallery]