# Android - How to open a specific folder in a gallery using an implicit intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

We are building a camera app that saves photos in a specific folder in the gallery. And we have to open the folder of our app in the gallery using an intent. We are using this code however it shows all folders.

```
View.OnClickListener goToGallery = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display images from a specific folder on android gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418807/how-can-i-display-images-from-a-specific-folder-on-android-gallery)

Answer (score 0):

To open gallery I use this intent.

```
public static final int RESULT_GALLERY = 0;
```

`Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,`                       `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`

`startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , RESULT_GALLERY );`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, we don't need to select a photo, we just need to view the photos inside our folder in the gallery :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but try replacing ACTION_PICK with ACTION_VIEW for my above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
It will retrieve view pictures under `storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyAppPics`
You can change the file path according to your directory path.

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File f = new File(sdDir, "MyAppPics");

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.fromFile(f), "/MyAppPics"), "image/*");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: For this to work, is it mandatory to have images in storage/emulated/0/Pictures? My images are in a folder in internal memory. And this solution doesn't work for it.