# Select multiple images from Gallery in Android and upload to Server in PHP

Tags: php, android, image-uploading

I am working with one application that have one functionality to select multiple images from android inbuilt Gallery/Camera.

> Gallery is open successfully using below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

**but I am able to select only One image from Gallery. so please suggest me how to select multiple images from inbuilt gallery and save to server.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426113/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-android

Comment: **Thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367671/5505680) is how to select multiple item fro a List view.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419045/5505680) is how to list the content of a directory.

So List the content, display it. Done, so simple.