# Open Android galley on specific folder

Tags: android

I wish to open android default gallery on specific folder. The folder contains images and videos. I can open the galley with:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType("media/*");
startActivity(i);
```

but how to do it in specific folder? I do not wish to read back the image or video viewed, just open it.

Comment: take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019534/gallery-with-folder-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code.

```
public void openFolder()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/myFolder/");

intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Permisson in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10749615/1405983).

Comment: Where you use thr uri variable?