# Open all image from specific folder in Android default gallery

Tags: android, image, video, uri, gallery

My requirement is to open all images and video's of specific folder.
I have refereed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749351/how-to-open-one-particular-folder-from-gallery-in-android/10749615#10749615) link, Now I am able to show a image in gallery but I want to show all images from a specific folder. Almost all link I have tried on stack but did not get success.

Answer (score 1):

You can set path in File object initialize at that time.
File folder = new File("/sdcard/Photo/");  in this tutorial default path is /sdcard/photo/ at this place you can set your path then get your files.

Comment: I have already made this changes in code but did not get success.

Comment: you can specify path that path available or not??

Comment: please check exception and find the solution

Comment: Now I am able to show a single photo that means I am not get any error or exception but I want to show multiple photo that should swipe right and left.

Answer (score 0):

I sinc it is not good idea but you may write your own searcher in all files on mobile phone for example

```
public ArrayList<File> getAllphotos(String path){
    ArrayList<File> photoPath = new ArrayList<>();
    File yourDir = new File(path);
    for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
        String mas[] = f.toString().split("\\.");
        if(mas[mas.length - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("png") || mas[mas.length - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")){//or other formats
            //it is picture
            photoPath.add(f);
        }
    }
    return photoPath;
}
```

call this wis iternal and external storage