# Opening a folder in the gallery

Tags: java, android

I read a lot of questions and answers about opening a specific folder in gallery. And I am not sure if it is even possible to do that. A lot of questions was pretty old though so I don't know if something changed in the meanwhile.

So I want to open a folder from the gallery app. I managed to open a single image from gallery using [MediaScannerConnectionClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749351/how-to-open-one-particular-folder-from-gallery-in-android), but what I really want is to open an entire folder with all the images displayed for user to open or delete. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I really want is to open an entire folder with all the images displayed for user to open or delete. Is this possible?

If you create your own gallery-style UI in your own app that offers these features, then yes.

If you are expecting to be able to do this with the hundreds of "gallery" apps that are in use today, then no.