# Open a specific folder (not a image) in Gallery in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, intentfilter

I write this code which open gallery with all folder:

```
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But I want to open an specific folder with built-in Gallery. I search about this and I found some people posted about this problem in stack overflow but there was no perfect sollution in any post. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "But I want to open an specific folder with built-in Gallery" -- there are hundreds of "built-in Gallery" apps, spread across the > 26,000 Android device models. None have to support any `Intent` action to show some specific image collection, such as what is contained in a filesystem directory.

Answer (score 0):

The location of photos is always the same - it’s the DCIM/Camera folder. The full path looks like this:

- /storage/emmc/DCIM - if the images are on the phone memory.
- /storage/sdcard0/DCIM - if they are on memory card.

OR by code.

```
private static String getGalleryPath() {
        return photoDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/";   
    }
```

and to open these specific folders you can [follow this answer.][1]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10749615/1371792